# How to run wine command through PHP script

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, lamp, ubuntu-16.04, wine

Need to run wine command through PHP script. As i have a .exe file , that should be executed with parameter using my PHP script. BTW , i am using LAMP. php scripts location is as-usual in lamp.

Tried:

```
exec('wine Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/fisrt_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/rc3.xml');
```

wine is working fine whenever i am executing from terminal.

my command :

```
wine Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/first_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/converted.xml
```

Please help....

Thanks
Raja Chakraborty

Comment: The commands you attempt are different between CLI and PHP attempt. _Why?_

Comment: What kind of application is that you are trying to execute? You certainly can not open some programm with a graphical UI (window) from within a typical PHP script requested via an http server.

Comment: why have you not tried `exec('wine Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/first_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/converted.xml);`

Comment: Thanks for reply
it's edi parser software  X12Parser.exe 
@Jason , yup i have tried that also. no result.

Comment: Hi All, 
Found this thread, but still it's not clear for me. as my reputation is below 50 can not able to comment on that thread. can anyone please explain ....below point...
"You should create a separate home directory for running Wine. Create a directory which is owned by www-data, set the HOME variable, su www-data, and run winecfg once; then run tool.exe (as that user). In the exec call, make sure that HOME is set (try exec("HOME=/tmp/wine wine tool.exe"))"

Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377388/how-to-use-wine-from-apache-php-var-www-is-not-owned-by-you

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
So Finally, used 'mono' command and run through PHP script.
Here is my command:

```
shell_exec('mono Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/first_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/firstXML.xml');
```

Thanks for the help guys
Raja Chakraborty